# Spring MVC -JSP-How Can I Get Session Atribute I JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, session, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Hi I' m coding basic personal blog management system with spring mvc and jsp.I want to make page info/error notification.İf wanted blog is not exists the error message is added to httpSesion and the error message will appear in jsp page.

I have NotificationMessage model , NotificationService interface and it' implementation as follow.

***NotificationMessage class***

```
package com.fatih.blogproject.model;

public class NotificationMessage {


private NotificationMessageType type;
private String text;

public NotificationMessage(NotificationMessageType type, String text) {
    this.type = type;
    this.text = text;
}

public NotificationMessageType getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
}
```

***NotificationService interface***

```
package com.fatih.blogproject.service;

public interface NotifiacationService {
void addInfoMessage(String msg);
void addErrorMessage(String msg);
}
```

***implementation of interface***

```
package com.fatih.blogproject.service.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.fatih.blogproject.model.NotificationMessage;
import com.fatih.blogproject.model.NotificationMessageType;
import com.fatih.blogproject.service.NotifiacationService;

@Service
public class NotificationServiceImpl implements NotifiacationService{

//Bu servis bilgi ve error mesajlarını HTTPSession içinde uzun süre tutmaya 
göre ayarlı olacak.
//HTTPSession içinde veriler key value çifti olarak tututlurlar.

 public static final String NOTIFY_MSG_SESSION_KEY = 
 "siteNotificationMessages";

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;



@Override
public void addInfoMessage(String msg) {
    addNotificationMessage(NotificationMessageType.INFO, msg);

}

@Override
public void addErrorMessage(String msg) {
    addNotificationMessage(NotificationMessageType.ERROR, msg);

}

private void addNotificationMessage(NotificationMessageType type , String msg){

    List<NotificationMessage> notifyMessage = (List<NotificationMessage>)httpSession.getAttribute(NOTIFY_MSG_SESSION_KEY);

    if(notifyMessage==null){
        notifyMessage=new ArrayList<NotificationMessage>();
    }
    notifyMessage.add(new NotificationMessage(type, msg));

    httpSession.setAttribute(NOTIFY_MSG_SESSION_KEY, notifyMessage);



}

}
```

***HomeController***

```
package com.fatih.blogproject.controller;



import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;
import com.fatih.blogproject.model.Post;
import com.fatih.blogproject.service.NotifiacationService;
import com.fatih.blogproject.service.PostService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {


private PostService postService;
private NotifiacationService notifyService;

@Autowired
public HomeController(PostService postService , NotifiacationService notifyService) {
    this.notifyService=notifyService;
    this.postService=postService;
}




@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model){

    List<Post> latest5Posts=postService.findLatest5();



    model.addAttribute("latest5Posts",latest5Posts);

    List<Post> latest3Posts=latest5Posts.stream()
            .limit(3)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    model.addAttribute("latest3Posts", latest3Posts);

    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping("/post/{id}")
public String post(@PathVariable("id") Long id  ,Model model){

    Post post=postService.findById(id);

    if(post==null){
        notifyService.addErrorMessage(id+"id li post bulunamadı");

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String date = formatter.format(post.getDate());


    model.addAttribute("post", post);
    model.addAttribute("date",date);
    return "post";
}




}
```

I want to access session value for notification mesage and view it in index.jsp

How can i do this?

I try this code in index page

```
<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("siteNotificationMessages") %>
```

but this code give me output in index page as follow

***[com.fatih.blogproject.model.NotificationMessage@1474487e]***

Note:I see this project from a tutorial that linked bellow.

[tutorial-link](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2016/08/05/creating-a-blog-system-with-spring-mvc-thymeleaf-jpa-and-mysql/)

The tutorial use Thymeleaf instead of jsp.The thymeleaf code in tutorial as follow

```
 <ul id="messages" th:with="notifyMessages=${session[T(blog.services
      .NotificationServiceImpl).NOTIFY_MSG_SESSION_KEY]}">
  <li th:each="msg : ${notifyMessages}" th:text="${msg.text}"
       th:class="${#strings.toLowerCase(msg.type)}">
  </li>
  <span th:if="${notifyMessages}" th:remove="all" th:text="${session.remove(
      T(blog.services.NotificationServiceImpl).NOTIFY_MSG_SESSION_KEY)}">
 </span>

</ul>
```

How can I convert this thymeleaf code to jsp?

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NotificationMessage` instance is returned so on the page the object's `toString()` method is called. You need to cast the returned object to NotificationMessage and use available methods.

```
<%=((NotificationMessage)request.getSession().getAttribute("siteNotificationMessages")).getMsg() %>
```

or

```
<%=((NotificationMessage)request.getSession().getAttribute("siteNotificationMessages")).getType() %>
```

depending on what you really need to show.

Comment: Yes. You will have NPE if the message is not set. Just add the null check.